# PyQt_PyObject equivalent when using new-style signals/slots?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, signals, signals-slots

So I have a need to pass around a numpy array in my PyQt Application. I first tried using the new-style signals/slots, defining my signal with:

`newChunkToProcess = pyqtSignal(np.array())`, however this gives the error:
TypeError: Required argument 'object' (pos 1) not found

I have worked out how to do this with the old-style signals and slots using 
`self.emit(SIGNAL("newChunkToProcess(PyQt_PyObject)"), np.array([5,1,2]))` - (yes, that's just testing data :), but I was wondering, is it possible to do this using the new-style system?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The type you're looking for is np.ndarray
You can tell this from the following code:

```
>>> arr = np.array([])  # create an array instance
>>> type(arr)           # ask 'what type is this object?'
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So your signal should look more like:

```
newChunkToProcess = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
```

(Notice I'm passing the *type* np.ndarray, rather than an array *instance* as you tried).
If you don't want to worry about the type of the argument, you could instead use:

```
newChunkToProcess = pyqtSignal(object)
```

This should let you send any data type at all through the signal.

Also: numpy and Qt do not share any major functionality that I know of. In fact, the two are quite complementary and make a very powerful combination.

Comment: Thanks, this was for a university project which is now history, but some good tips there :)

Answer (score -4):

You are doing it wrong. You have to pass the data object type: int, str, ... in your case list

Like I am doing:

```
images = pyqtSignal(int, str);
failed = pyqtSignal(str, str);
finished = pyqtSignal(int)
```

Comment: What's the type for numpy arrays then?