# PyQt signal with arguments of arbitrary type / PyQt_PyObject equivalent for new-style signals

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals

I have an object that should signal that a value has changed by emitting a signal with the new value as an argument. The type of the value can change, and so I'm unsure of how to write the signal type. I know that I can acconmplish this using old-style signals like this:

```
self.emit(SIGNAL("valueChanged(PyQt_PyObject)"), newvalue)
```

but how would I write this using new-style signals?

I am aware of [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756510/pyqt-pyobject-equivalent-when-using-new-style-signals-slots) related to this but no "real" answer was given there.

Answer (score 24):

First, the object you're emitting from needs the signal defined as an attribute of its *class*:

```
class SomeClass(QObject):
    valueChanged = pyqtSignal(object)
```

Notice the signal has one argument of type *object*, which should allow anything to pass through. Then, you should be able to emit the signal from within the class using an argument of any data type:

```
self.valueChanged.emit(anyObject)
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm a beginner and this is the first question I'm attempting to answer, so apologies if I have misunderstood the question...

The following code emits a signal that sends a custom Python object, and the slot uses that
class to print "Hello World".

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject

class NativePythonObject(object):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def printMessage(self):
        print(self.message)
        sys.exit()

class SignalEmitter(QObject):
    theSignal = pyqtSignal(NativePythonObject)

    def __init__(self, toBeSent, parent=None):
        super(SignalEmitter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.toBeSent = toBeSent

    def emitSignal(self):
        self.theSignal.emit(toBeSent)

class ClassWithSlot(object):
    def __init__(self, signalEmitter):
        self.signalEmitter = signalEmitter
        self.signalEmitter.theSignal.connect(self.theSlot)

    def theSlot(self, ourNativePythonType):
        ourNativePythonType.printMessage()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toBeSent = NativePythonObject("Hello World")
    signalEmitter = SignalEmitter(toBeSent)
    classWithSlot = ClassWithSlot(signalEmitter)
    signalEmitter.emitSignal()
```

Comment: That would probably work, but is even uglier than using the old-style API I showed in my original question.