# pyqt signal emit with object instance or None

Tags: python, parameters, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

I would like to have a pyqt signal, which can either emit with a python "object" subclass argument or None. For example, I can do this:

```
valueChanged = pyqtSignal([MyClass], ['QString'])
```

but not this:

```
valueChanged = pyqtSignal([MyClass], ['None'])
TypeError: C++ type 'None' is not supported as a pyqtSignal() type argument type
```

or this:

```
valueChanged = pyqtSignal([MyClass], [])
TypeError: signal valueChanged[MyObject] has 1 argument(s) but 0 provided
```

I also tried None without the quotes and the c++ equivalent "NULL". But neither seems to work. What is it I need to do to make this work?

Comment: I think [this][1] answer might do what you want 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5186587/1332492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**; There's no real solution to this problem. PyQt treats `None` in a special way when defining signal overloads, so the simplest solution is to use `object` instead. For an explanation of exactly why this is, see below.

---

There are a couple of reasons why what you tried didn't work.

Firstly, the `type` argument of `pyqtSignal` accepts either a python *type-object* or a string giving the name of a C++ object (i.e. a Qt class). Strings can't be used to specify python types - and in any case, `None` is a *value*, not a type.

Secondly, `None` is special-cased by PyQt to allow the default overload of the signal to be used without explicitly selecting the signature. So, even if `type(None)` were used when defining signal overloads, *it still wouldn't solve the problem*.

(With hindsight, it appears that a better design choice would have been for PyQt to use an internal sentinel object for the default, rather than special-casing `None`. However, it's possibly too late to change that now. The behaviour remains unchanged in PyQt5 & PyQt6 [as of 13-03-2023]).

Just to spell this all out more clearly, here's some example code:

```
class MyClass: pass

class X(QtCore.QObject):
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal([MyClass], [type(None)])

x = X()
x.valueChanged.connect(
    lambda *a: print('valueChanged[]:', a))
x.valueChanged[MyClass].connect(
    lambda *a: print('valueChanged[MyClass]:', a))
x.valueChanged[type(None)].connect(
    lambda *a: print('valueChanged[type(None)]:', a))

print('emit: valueChanged[]')
x.valueChanged.emit(MyClass())
print('\nemit: valueChanged[type(None)]')
x.valueChanged[type(None)].emit(MyClass())
print('\nemit: valueChanged[MyClass]')
x.valueChanged[MyClass].emit(MyClass())
```

Output:

```
emit: valueChanged[]
valueChanged[]: (<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f37ab0db8e0>,)
valueChanged[MyClass]: (<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f37ab0db8e0>,)
valueChanged[type(None)]: (<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f37ab0db8e0>,)

emit: valueChanged[type(None)]
valueChanged[]: (<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f37ab0db8e0>,)
valueChanged[MyClass]: (<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f37ab0db8e0>,)
valueChanged[type(None)]: (<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f37ab0db8e0>,)

emit: valueChanged[MyClass]
valueChanged[]: (<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f37ab0db940>,)
valueChanged[MyClass]: (<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f37ab0db940>,)
valueChanged[type(None)]: (<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f37ab0db940>,)
```

As you can see, when `type(None)` is used as an overload, it becomes impossible to select anything other than the *default overload* (i.e. the first one specified in the list of arguments). All three behave in exactly the same way, because they all select the same `MyClass` overload.

This also means that attempting to emit `None` will fail, because that value can never match the type of the selected overload (which defaults to `MyClass`).

A simple work-around would be to use `object` instead of `type(None)` - but this has the downside of allowing literally *any* value to be passed. So if preserving type is important, another possible solution might be to define your own singleton sentinel class to use instead of `None`.

Answer (score 5):

A hacky workaround for this is to define your signal to emit `object`. Since `None` and `MyClass` both inherit from `object` it works as expected. This requires no casting in the slot.

Working in PyQt5 5.11.3 and Python 3.5.6

Signal

```
valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

valueChanged.emit(MyClass())
valueChanged.emit(None)
```

Slot

```
valueChanged.connect(slot)

def slot(my_class_instance):
    if my_class_instance:
        my_class_instance.some_method()
    else:
        # my_class_instance is None
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify a second option - it will be accepting a pointer for your class type, which can already be a None value:

```
valueChanged = pyqtSignal(MyClass)

# both will work as is
inst.valueChanged.emit(MyClass())
inst.valueChanged.emit(None)
```

Comment: Is there any way for this to work with PyQt5 / Python 3.5+ then? I can only think of passing a wrapper class to the signal instead, i.e. a class with a single attribute which can be either None or a MyClass object. It seems a bit overkill to me though.

Comment: @FernAndr Its a few years later, but if you look at my answer there is already a standard python object None and your custom type have in common - the object type.