# PySide/Qt: How do I return an object from a function connected to an event?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to get a grasp on PySide and Gui Programming but I'm stuck at the moment. This is what I want to accomplish:

- load a UI file that contains fields and buttons to logon to a SAP system
- A user enters the credentials and clicks on the 'logon' button.
- function connect_client() is started. Within the function a pyrfc.connection objects gets created.

Is there a way to use the methods of the connection object in the main program? Perhaps like it would be in a normal function that just returns the object? Here is the code that may explain it a litte more. It would be great if anybody could push me in the right direction:

```
def connect_client():
    conndetails=dict()
    conndetails['user']=str(MainWindow.username.text())
    conndetails['ashost']=str(MainWindow.hostname.text())
    conndetails['passwd']=str(MainWindow.password.text())
    conndetails['sysnr']=str(MainWindow.systemnumber.text())
    conndetails['client']=str(MainWindow.client.text())
    abapclient=sap_abapclient(**conndetails)
    return(abapclient)                     <-is there a way to do something like this?


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = loadUiWidget("rsusr002_gui.ui")
    MainWindow.btnLogon.clicked.connect(connect_client)
    general = sap_general()
    variants = general.read_suim_variants_from_file('variants.cfg')
    variant_model=QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    for row in variants.keys():
        item=QtGui.QStandardItem(row)
        variant_model.appendRow(item)
    MainWindow.lstChecks.setModel(variant_model)
    MainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

A common pattern is to create a QObject-derived class and make `connect_client` a slot in that class. Connect statement will look like `...clicked.connect(my_object.connect_client)`. In this case you can store any data in the object (e.g. `self.abapclient = abapclient`) and use it later when you like.

`main` will have access to the object and therefore its properties and methods. However this is no use for you because main will always be busy executing `app.exec_()`. At the time `connect_client` is called, you can no longer perform any actions in `main`. Basically, all work should be done in slots, and it's convenient to put slots in a class so they can store a program state in object properties and share access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the object as argument to the slot. Just give the class of object that is sent to connected slots as part of the `pyqtSignal`, like `pyqtSignal(YourClass)`. More details are provided in @HansHermans answer at [PyQt signal with arguments of arbitrary type / PyQt_PyObject equivalent for new-style signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523006/pyqt-signal-with-arguments-of-arbitrary-type-pyqt-pyobject-equivalent-for-new).

Comment: Is it fine to refer to some post by answer number? Like you wrote *2nd answer*. Because the order of posts/answers changes as the number of up votes and down votes increases or decreases!